# How do I make a smooth transition between two Lottie animations?

Tags: android, lottie

I have a problem with LottieAnimation lib. I need to make a smooth transition between two animations. To put simply it should be:

1. First animation is shown
2. When the first animation ends, second appears
3. The second animation shoud be looped until user clicks continue button.

I've tried to do that using AnimationListener("onAnimationEnd" or something like that) but it didn't work for me because there was a blinking effect between two animations.